# db2 select statement from a table name where the table name is a variable

Tags: count, db2

I need to select all the table row count from a `db2` database.

I have a query to select all the schema and table name:

```
select rtrim(tabschema)||'.'||rtrim(tabname) as tableName from syscat.tables where tabschema = 'COM' order by tabname;
```

This query give me list of the table name of the database.

I would like to do something like:

```
select count(*) from tableFromTheFirstQuery
```

Where the tableFromThePreviousQuery is subsitute by the tableName of my first query.

I can not do like

```
select count(*) from (select rtrim(tabschema)||'.'||rtrim(tabname) as tableName from syscat.tables where tabschema = 'COM' order by tabname);
```

I will only get result of count of my first query.

I am not sure the way is exist or not. Basically I need to save all the table row counts in a text file before doing DR activity.

Kindly advise

Comment: You can put that into a stored procedure. There are SO answers that show how to execute a dynamic statement in a SP. Make sure not to block the entire database and use UR for isolation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a compound statement like this

```
CREATE TABLE COUNT_ROWS (
    TABSCHEMA  VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
,   TABNAME    VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
,   ROW_COUNT   BIGINT
)
@
BEGIN
    FOR C AS cur CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR
        SELECT 'INSERT INTO COUNT_ROWS SELECT ''' || TABSCHEMA || ''',''' || TABNAME || ''', COUNT(*) FROM '
            || '"' ||  TABSCHEMA || '"."' || TABNAME || '"' AS S
        FROM SYSCAT.TABLES
        WHERE TYPE = 'T' AND TABSCHEMA NOT LIKE 'SYS%'
        WITH UR
    DO
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE C.S;
          COMMIT;
    END FOR;
END
@
SELECT * FROM COUNT_ROWS
@
```

Note that you will need to use `@` as your statement terminator to get the above to run